# How to parse this json with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Hi i am new to json and have some problems in parsing a JSON file with jQuery.

json file is here - http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=27.88,78.08&sensor=false

and i am parsing it like this

```
var url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=" + area.getCenter().lat + "," + area.getCenter().lng + "&sensor=false";
$.getJSON(url, function(data) {
    console.log("insidegetjson");
    console.log(data);
    var addr = data.results[0].formatted_address[0];
});
```

here i want to access first  "formatted_address" part of the JSON. I know i am making a mistake here  (i want    "formatted_address" : "Achal Taal, Aligarh, Uttar Pradesh 202001, India",)

```
var addr = data.results[0].formatted_address[0];
```

can you please replace this sentence with correct sentence...thanks

Comment: @ScottHarwell The question you linked to has no relation with this one. Please don't vote to close just because you've read the title of the question.

Comment: I went by them, and it states that var addr = data.results[0].formatted_address; should be correct. But i don't know whats wrong here(( @FelixKling

Comment: @dystroy I read the question.  It's been asked many different ways before.

Comment: @ScottHarwell Since the first iteration, OP was using $.getJSON

Answer (score 2):

Remove the last [0] :

```
var addr = data.results[0].formatted_address;
```

`data.results[0].formatted_address` isn't an array but a string.

Comment: I used data.results[0].formatted_address initially but it couldn't help. It shows UNDEFINED value.